GitHub split-tests Action: Cannot Use junit-path Parameter Correctly
I am using the split-tests GitHub Action to split my tests into groups so they can be run in parallel using a matrix runner on GitHub.
successfully implemented a pipeline to split the tests, execute them, generate a JUnit report, and cache the JUnit results. You can find here the project for reference.
My next step is to pass the cached JUnit results to the split-tests action so it can use a more efficient splitting strategy based on test execution time instead of file count.
However, the split-tests action is reporting an error that the required JUnit XML file cannot be found:
shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    total-runners: 5
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Zulu_jdk/17.0.12-7/x64
    JAVA_HOME_17_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Zulu_jdk/17.0.12-7/x64
    GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_SETUP_COMPLETED: true
    GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_CACHE_RESTORED: true
    use_junit_results: true

junit-path set. Splitting based on JUnit timings
using test times from JUnit report ./unified-test-results/unified-report.xml
missing file time for parallel-backend-tests/core/src/test/java/org/parallel/huge/HugeExecution7Test.java
missing file time for parallel-backend-tests/core/src/test/java/org/parallel/huge/HugeExecution9Test.java
missing file time for parallel-backend-tests/core/src/test/java/org/parallel/huge/HugeExecution2Test.java
missing file time for parallel-backend-tests/core/src/test/java/org/parallel/medium/MediumExecution7Test.java
missing file time for parallel-backend-tests/core/src/test/java/org/parallel/huge/HugeExecutionTest.java

I have cached the individual JUnit XML files generated by the tests, but these files are stored in a flat folder structure, which does not mirror the project's directory structure.
I then tried merging the individual XML files into a single XML file, but this approach didn't work either.
The split-tests GitHub Action uses CircleCI under the hood, but its documentation on handling JUnit XML files is unclear to me.
How can I make the split-tests GitHub Action correctly map the Java classes to the corresponding JUnit XML result files?
For reference, the flat hierarchy of my JUnit XML files looks like this:
TEST-org.parallel.big.BigExecution2Test.xml
TEST-org.parallel.big.BigExecution7Test.xml
TEST-org.parallel.huge.HugeExecution4Test.xml
TEST-org.parallel.huge.HugeExecutionTest.xml
TEST-org.parallel.medium.MediumExecution6Test.xml
TEST-org.parallel.small.SmallExecution3Test.xml
TEST-org.parallel.small.SmallExecution3Test.xml

Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
